# Using SSL on nginx in a Docker container hosted on Jelastic

Tags: ssl, docker, jelastic

I have a Docker container with nginx running on Jelastic. From the container I used certbot to get a ssl certificate from letsencrypt. Finally I changed the nginx conf accordingly. I have not enble ssl in the Jelastic user interface.

When browsing the site on https it seems that I get the generic certificate of the Jelastic provider but not my own certificate, because the error is  SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN the ssl certificate served is for the domain of the provider. But I have not enabled the ssl on the Jelastic interface ?!

So can I use a letsencrypt ssl certificate in my docker container on Jelastic and how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use custom SSL cert without public IP.
In this case, all external traffic is going through the platform revers-proxies wich is providing platform shared SSL.

The solution is to use external IP.

Comment: Thanks, I activated the external IP, changed  the dns accordingly and it wroks.

Comment: Although I wish I would not have to use a static ip just for that. Anyone knows if the custom ssl for Docker in Jelastic will be available soon ?

Comment: When you are working w/o public IP, all traffic is going through the revers-proxies. Because of this topology, there is no way to use custom SSL without public IP.